# How to trigger mouseout in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have to close panel when mouse leave the panel itself don't know how to do it, if you have some ideas how to trigger this event please. (mouseleave is ont working)

```
<mat-autocomplete (mouseleave)="closePanel()" autoActiveFirstOption >
<mat-option  *ngFor="let tag of this.sourceFiltered$ | async; trackBy: optionTrackByFn" [value]="tag"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tag">
      <div class="tag-name mat-body-2">{{tag.name}}</div>
      <div class="tag-category mat-caption">{{tag.category}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div (mouseover)="changeText=true" (mouseout)="changeText=false">
<span *ngIf="!changeText">Hide</span>
 <span *ngIf="changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```